# Capture google app engine logging output

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

How can one view the Google App Engine logs outside the Admin console?

I'm developing, so using `dev_appserver.py`/the Admin Console and would like to see the logs as the records are emitted.

I'd like to monitor the logging output in a console with standard Unix tools e.g. less/grep/etc, but there doesn't seem to be an option to direct the logging from the `dev_appserver.py` command, and I can't open a new file in GAE (e.g. a FileHandler), so file handlers won't work, and I think using a socket/udp handler would be a bit of overkill (if it's even possible).

I'm hopeful there are other options to view the log.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: GAE forum discussion: http://code.google.com/appengine/forum/python-forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-appengine-python%2FsMfaGtLiV7M%2Fdiscussion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default logger sends logging output to `stderr`. Use your shell's method of redirecting `stderr` to a file (in tcsh, `(dev_appserver.py > /dev/tty) >& your_logfile.txt`, your shell may vary.)

You can also use the `logging` module in python to change the logger to send directly to a file if you detect it's running locally (`os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Dev')`)

Comment: Can the `logging` module write to a file from GAE? Aren't file operations prohibited (except w/testbed, now)? Wouldn't the only option be a logger to a socket or HTTP or some such?

Comment: @Brian: the App Engine sandbox is irrelevant here; this solution involves the shell redirecting the output to a file on your local machine (where the filesystem is presumably writable). Obviously this won't work on the production servers, but it's also unnecessary there because the logs are saved for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the logs using the `request_logs` parameter of `appcfg.py`

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Logs

Edit:
This person came up with a way to send logs over XMPP. His solution is for GAE Java, but this could be adapted to python.

http://www.professionalintellectualdevelopment.com/

http://code.google.com/p/gae-xmpp-logger/

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: I want to get the logs while developing (hence the reference to `dev_appserver.py). Otherwise I think you've got the correct answer. :)