# How to decode the persisted log files from App Engine's Python Dev_server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

Using Google App Engine's local dev_server, one of the  [published options](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/#Python_The_development_server_and_Logs_API)  is to save the log files to disk.

> "If you wish to persist the logs from the development server to disk at a location of your own >choosing, supply the desired path and filename to the --logs_path command line option as follows:
>
> dev_appserver.py --logs_path=your-path/your-logfile-name your-app-directory"

This works except the files are in a binary format I can't decode.

Google published some [sample code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/#Python_Getting_log_data) but this is intended for an app to read the production logs.

Is there a command line utlity or python script that can decode the log files stored by the dev_server? This was submitted as a [feature request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128393/google-app-engine-logging-in-dev-console) in 2011.

I can see the logs in the PyDev console as they are produced, but once the current execution is restarted, those logs are gone from that console.

There are some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757945/capture-google-app-engine-logging-output) to pipe the logfile unix style, but this does not help with the logs already stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logfile created is a SQLite database. Use the [`sqlite3` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) to access it.

The schema used is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AppLogs (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  request_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  timestamp INTEGER NOT NULL,
  level INTEGER NOT NULL,
  message TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(request_id) REFERENCES RequestLogs(id)
);
CREATE TABLE RequestLogs (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_request_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  app_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  version_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  module TEXT NOT NULL,
  ip TEXT NOT NULL,
  nickname TEXT NOT NULL,
  start_time INTEGER NOT NULL,
  end_time INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  method TEXT NOT NULL,
  resource TEXT NOT NULL,
  http_version TEXT NOT NULL,
  status INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  response_size INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  user_agent TEXT NOT NULL,
  url_map_entry TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  host TEXT NOT NULL,
  task_queue_name TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  task_name TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  latency INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  mcycles INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);
```

`RequestLogs` contains HTTP requests (from a browser or a task queue); `AppLogs` contains any logging entries recorded during a specific request.

Comment: #Thanks, I tried this and it works. 

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('bunjilae.log')

c = conn.cursor()

i = 0

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM AppLogs ORDER BY timestamp'):

        print row